# Modifying an instance of string

Tags: ruby, string, mutable

I have a string:

```
str="D\\projects\\myown\\java"
```

I assigned this string to two variables like:

```
str1=str
str2=str
```

After I did the below operation:

```
idgb1=str1.gsub!("\\","_")
```

I get `str1` as `D_projects_myown_java` and `str2` is the same. why does this happen? I don't want `str2` to change its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str1` and `str2` are just references to `str`, the string is not copied to those variables. And `String#gsub!` updates the string in place.

If you want to keep `str2` intact, you need to do it like this:

```
str2 = str.dup
```

or

```
str2 = str.clone
```

Besides, if you use `String#gsub` instead of `String#gsub!`, `str` and `str2` will not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

for further information you might also want to read up on shallow vs deep copies, here a link to Wikipedia that explains the concept:
[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy)

Also in addition, I wanted to add, that the '!' usually identifies what are called 'bang methods'. These are methods that ultimately alter the state of the variable they're called on.

This link touches upon bang methods and actually has an example which is very similar to the problem you described: 
[enter link description here](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist)

Hope this helps